# What is the definition of the Feferman-Levy model?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

Any (reference to) definition of Feferman-Levy model in set theory?
I cannot find any...
Though I know what is Levy collapse.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Feferman-Levy model is described in Jech **The Axiom of Choice** in Chapter 10 (Theorem 10.6), as well you can find nice detailed accounts in both Arnie Miller's papers about Dedekind-finite Borel sets and Long Borel Hierarchies (both of which you can find [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/index.html)), as well Ioanna Dimitriou M.Sc. and Ph.D. thesis (both of which [appear here](https://ioa.re/#publications)).

The idea is that we begin with $L$ (at least in the classical settings, we don't have to in general), then we use the forcing $\Bbb P=\prod_{n\in\omega}\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\omega_n)$, and take all the names which are fully decided in a finite stage of the product.

This can be given a nice symmetric extension presentation as well. Note that conditions in $\Bbb P$ are finite functions accepting pairs of integers, and $p(m,n)<\omega_m$. Now take permutations which move for each $m$ separately, then $n$ coordinate. Then take the filter of subgroups of those fixing finitely many $m$'s.

Comment: Since the OP says (s)he knows about the Levy collapse, the following remarks might be useful. The forcing Levy collapses all cardinals below $\aleph_\omega$ to $\omega$, but that does not make $\aleph_\omega$ the new $\aleph_1$, because it's singular (and AC implies $\aleph_1$ is regular). Passing to the symmetric submodel discards the countings of (the old) $\aleph_\omega$ so that it becomes $\aleph_1$, yet remains singular.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Andreas.

Comment: *and take all the names which are fully decided in a finite stage of the product*. Regarding the exposition in Cohen IV.10, this is not an adequate description, as one has to add a name for the sequence of countable symmetric hulls of the collapsing functions, see i and ii on p 144 in Cohen. This name involves all collapse functions, not some finite number of them.

Comment: @Vladimir: By homogeneity if something is forced about a symmetric name, it was forced by a uniform bound. This is what I meant by "fully decided".

Comment: The name for all functions from $\omega$ to $\aleph_\omega$ is as symmetric as one can imagine, but it cannot be added to the FL construction.

Comment: @Vladimir: I honestly have a hard time understanding the motivation for this particular discussion. I gave a reference to a correct proof, I gave a *gist* of the idea behind the construction. I could have easily provided a full account of the definition. But what for? Jech did it better. If you want to insist, Ioanna Dimitriou gave two excellent descriptions in her masters and doctorate dissertations. So, what exactly are we doing here?

Comment: I am sincerely sorry of this annoyance. Now writing a semiphilosophical paper in a collective, I am trying to present the FL model $N$ to a layman. Following Solovay, my first take was to define $N$ as all sets in $M[(f_n:n\in N)]$ hereditarily definable with parameters in $M$ and a finite number of $f_n$'s. But oops, $\aleph_1$ in *this* $N$ is ctbly cofinal, yes, but no proof that $R$ is a ctble union of ctble sets. Jech I found unreadable unless to first study all B-valued stuff. Then I found in Cohen the key ingredient, missing (I thought) in your Jul 25 '14. Thanks for attention.