# Can $ZF$ construct this function?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ordinals, constructive-mathematics

Is it possible in the $ZF$ theory to construct a function with domain $\omega_1$ (the set of all countable ordinals) that maps each countable ordinal $\alpha$ to a bijection between $\alpha$ and $\omega$?

I tried using some recursion and ended up constructing these up to $\epsilon_0$ (just then I found out about Cantor's normal form, this can indicate my knowledge about ordinals...). I figured that if I could construct for each countsble ordinal $\alpha$ some cofinal set for $\alpha$ that is not isomorphic to $\alpha$ itself then I could do this. Then I tried using the set of limit ordinals for that, repeating that step. I tried something else too later. But anyway, whatever I try I don't get further than $\epsilon_0$. That's probably because all my recursions revolve around basic ordinal operations: addition and multiplication. I am starting to doubt that it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that no such function exists. Indeed, Feferman and Levy proved that it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\omega_1$ is a countable union of countable sets (which obviously prevents such a function from existing, or perhaps more transparently *would* be prevented by the existence of such a function). Of course a proof of this is well beyond the scope of an MSE answer, but you can find relevant comments elsewhere on this site (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878146/what-is-the-definition-of-the-feferman-levy-model)).

That said, it's easy to get *well* beyond $\epsilon_0$. Note that $\epsilon_0$ is a **computable** ordinal: there is a computable binary relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $(\mathbb{N};R)\cong\epsilon_0$. Via "pick the least index for a computable presentation," we can get an explicit bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the smallest noncomputable ordinal $\omega_1^{CK}$. We can with more thought continue much further. Incidentally, for a nice summary of ordinals beyond $\omega_1^{CK}$, I recommend [this survey of Madore](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf).

(And of course $\mathsf{ZF}$ *does* prove "For each countable ordinal $\alpha$ there is a function $f$ sending each $\beta<\alpha$ to an injection $\beta\rightarrow\omega$.")

Comment: Thank you for answering! It took me a little while to understand it nicely, but I got it at the end. I just want to ask, what isthis "pick the least index for a computable presentation" actually doing? Can you add a few more details in that informal description of this algorithm please?

Comment: @cnikbesku You may identify an index of a computable presentation with a code for a computer program computing something (in this case, a computer program computing a specific countable well-order.) You may code computer programs into natural numbers, like turning a C code into ASCII code texts and turning the list of codes into a large natural number. This is not what mathematicians work with indices of computable functions, but might be a useful way to imagine the concept.